# How to replace nested for loop to Map and any way to reduce the time calculation part?

Tags: salesforce

How to replace the nested for loop with map?

HOW TO REPLACE THE NESTED FOR LOOP BY MAP

public class Casecal {
    public void calculatetime(List caseids,Map casemap){

```
    map<string,List<CaseMilestone>> milestonemap = new map<string,List<CaseMilestone>>();
    if(casemap!=null && caseids.size()>0){
        BusinessHours bh = [SELECT Id FROM BusinessHours WHERE IsDefault=true];
        List<Case> caselist = [Select id, (select caseId,id,isCompleted,MilestoneTypeId,BusinessHoursId,MilestoneType.name,CompletionDate from 
                                           CaseMilestones where(MilestoneType.name='First Response' or MilestoneType.name='Technical Resolution')
                                           AND caseid IN:casemap.keySet()) from case]; 

        for(Case cs: caselist ){
            milestonemap.put(cs.id,cs.Casemilestones);
        }
        for(Case c: caseids){
            if(c.Request_for_Closure_Date__c!=null && milestonemap.containskey(c.id) ){
                for(CaseMilestone ml:milestonemap.get(c.id)){
                    if(ml.MilestoneType.name=='First Response'){
                        Integer ms = Integer.valueOf((BusinessHours.diff(bh.id, ml.CompletionDate, c.Request_for_Closure_Date__c))/1000);
                        system.debug('Time@calculation'+ms);
                        Integer sec = ms;
                        Integer mns = sec/60;
                        integer days = mns / 60 / 24 ;
                        integer hours = (mns - days * 60 * 24) / 60 ;
                        integer mins = mns - days * 60 * 24 - hours * 60 ;
                        String timeSpentOnCase = days+'Days '+hours+'Hours '+mins+'Minutes'+sec+'Secs';
                        System.debug('Time'+timeSpentOnCase);

                        c.Test_Ignore__c = ml.CompletionDate;
                    }
                    else if(ml.MilestoneType.name=='Technical Resolution'){
                        c.Test_Ignore_2__c = ml.CompletionDate;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Thanks both of you, and how i have to modify my code to stop executing the queries if case dont have any milestones.

Comment: You aren't making any queries after the initial one. I'm not sure what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

These loops have already been optimized, but the Map-based data access is not actually necessary because the child objects are queried with the parents.

```
    for(Case cs: caselist ){
        milestonemap.put(cs.id,cs.Casemilestones);
    }
```

This is not needed at all and can be removed. Instead, change the inner `for` loop to refer to the child `CaseMilestones` list directly.

```
    for(Case c: caseids){
        if(c.Request_for_Closure_Date__c!=null){
            for(CaseMilestone ml : c.CaseMilestones){
```

The loop simply won't execute if `c.CaseMilestones` is empty.

There is no further Map-based optimization for this code.

Comment: if my Case don't have any milestones and 'Request_for_Closure_Date__c'  or 'Technical_resolution_or_Fixed_date__c' is changed my queries will run. is there a way to stop executing these queries in that point

Answer (score 1):

What David said in above comment, the access is pretty optimised as is.
If you seek further optimisation I'd:

- Move `if(c.Request_for_Closure_Date__c!=null` and improve the WHERE clause (why you want to retrieve some Cases if you skip them in processing?). So something like

  ```
  SELECT Id,
      (SELECT CaseId, Id, isCompleted...
      FROM CaseMilestones
      WHERE ...)
  FROM Case
  WHEREId IN :caseids AND Request_for_Closure_Date__c!=null
  ```
- throw this code away. If it's just for system.debug - you're just wasting the calculation time.

  ```
  Integer ms = Integer.valueOf((BusinessHours.diff(bh.id, ml.CompletionDate, c.Request_for_Closure_Date__c))/1000);
  system.debug('Time@calculation'+ms);
  Integer sec = ms;
  Integer mns = sec/60;
  integer days = mns / 60 / 24 ;
  integer hours = (mns - days * 60 * 24) / 60 ;
  integer mins = mns - days * 60 * 24 - hours * 60 ;
  String timeSpentOnCase = days+'Days '+hours+'Hours '+mins+'Minutes'+sec+'Secs';
  System.debug('Time'+timeSpentOnCase);
  ```

---

If after these 2 optimisations you still have performance problems then you might have to rethink your business logic and query. Is it guaranteed that there will be at most 1 milestone of each type on case?

Maybe you need a subquery with just one type that would give you latest milestone? Something like `SELECT Id, (SELECT CompletionDate FROM CaseMilestones WHERE Type = 'x' ORDER BY CompletionDate DESC LIMIT 1) FROM Case`? Then you run this query for second type and process. Ok, wastes 2 queries but guaranteed to return only few rows.

Or maybe you can simplify this code completely by doing something like

```
SELECT CaseId, MAX(CompletionDate) d, MilestoneType.Name t
FROM CaseMilestone
WHERE CaseId IN :... AND MilestoneType.Name IN :...
GROUP BY CaseId, MilestoneType.Name
```

Comment: if my case dont have any mile stones. how can i stop executing both queries.How to check earlier.

Comment: You mean argument passed to your function? Modify the query to say `SELECT Id, ... FROM Case WHERE ... AND Id IN (SELECT CaseId FROM CaseMilestone)`. It should nicely immediately filter out cases that don't have anything on the related list. If that still gives you performance problems - something's seriously wrong but probably somewhere else. You'd have to time it in a debug log to see where the real bottleneck is.